# Passing from a "lambda" function

Tags: python

In Python I'm using a class out of library. I only want to call certain functions if a certain parameter is set.

For example:

```
import pyserial

serialobj=serial.Serial()

parameter=0
#The part idk about
def serialobjpass()
     if parameter=1:
         pass Argument to serialobj.
```

`serialobj` might be `serialobj.write()` or `serialobj.recieve()`
I would be just like a man in the middle to siphone out calls when i dont want them

Comment: Please add some example code which shows how you use (call) `serialobjpass`.

Comment: just like i would use serialobj just a man in the middle to spihon out calls when i dont want them

Comment: What does any of this have to do with lambdas?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your use case. To make it easier for others to understand what you need, as I originally asked, please add some example code which shows how you plan to use (call) `serialobjpass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```py
class Forwarder(object):
  def __init__(self, target):
    self.target = target
    self.parameter = 1
  def read(self, n):
    print(('READ', n))
    if self.parameter:
      return self.target.read(n)
    else:
      return 0
  def write(self, data):
    print(('WRITE', data))
    if self.parameter:
      return self.target.write(data)
    else:
      return len(data)

import pyserial
serialobj = Forwarder(serial.Serial())
...
serialobj.write('HELLO\r\n')
print([serialobj.read(1)])
self.parameter = 0  # Prevent subsequent reads or writes.
serialobj.write('World\r\n')  # Won't be written to the serial port.
```

In this setup the the `Forwarder` object intercepts all calls to the `.read` and `.write` methods, and calls the original `.read` and `.write` methods depending on how the parameter is set.

Comment: Sure something like this would work. But i thought of a more dynamic solution

Comment: @Usus: Eactly what kind of solution were you expecting? The body of `read` and `write` contains custom logic, and it can't be autogenerated.